# How to interpret FPS report in a spindump output?

Tags: graphics, macos

In the end of spindump output produced by Activity Monitor one can find following section:

```
----FPS Report Legend:-----
Raw Instantaneous FPS:
    30FPS delimiter:    '|'
    10FPS delimiter:    '+'
    1FPS delimiter:     '-'

Defer+Work Instantaneous FPS:                'X'
Work Instantaneous FPS:                      '^'
Equal Work and Defer+Work Instantaneous FPS: '*'

====Frame Rate Report:====

   Frame Length [SampleRange] WS Wait Length [SampleRange]   Defer Length [SampleRange] WS Work Length [SampleRange]      Frame Rate
         0.53 ms[ No samples]         0.00 ms[ No samples]         0.00 ms[ No samples]         0.53 ms[ No samples]     1881.32 FPS|---------+---------+---------|---------+---------+---------*
        17.20 ms[    5-6    ]         6.94 ms[      5    ]         9.15 ms[      6    ]         1.11 ms[ No samples]       58.15 FPS|---------+---------+---------|---------+---------+-------- *
        17.91 ms[    7-8    ]         6.41 ms[      7    ]        10.60 ms[      8    ]         0.90 ms[ No samples]       55.84 FPS|---------+---------+---------|---------+---------+------   *
        14.96 ms[      9    ]         5.16 ms[ No samples]         9.13 ms[      9    ]         0.67 ms[ No samples]       66.84 FPS|---------+---------+---------|---------+---------+---------*
        16.83 ms[   10-11   ]         6.87 ms[     10    ]         9.15 ms[     11    ]         0.80 ms[ No samples]       59.42 FPS|---------+---------+---------|---------+---------+---------*
        17.70 ms[   12-13   ]         6.67 ms[     12    ]        10.47 ms[     13    ]         0.56 ms[ No samples]       56.49 FPS|---------+---------+---------|---------+---------+------   *
        15.39 ms[     14    ]         5.63 ms[ No samples]         9.24 ms[     14    ]         0.52 ms[ No samples]       64.96 FPS|---------+---------+---------|---------+---------+---------*
        16.57 ms[   15-16   ]         6.87 ms[     15    ]         9.19 ms[     16    ]         0.52 ms[ No samples]       60.33 FPS|---------+---------+---------|---------+---------+---------*
...
```

It seems like second by second report how fast system was able to render frames in a last 5 minutes or so.

Unfortunately I can find no information about how to interpret this report correctly. Can some please explain it, or provide some additional sources I can read. In particular what are *Sample Range*, *WS Wait length*, *WS Work length* etc.

Comment: What are you actually trying to figure out? The Mac's fps will change depending on what's on show. A static desktop will be right down at 2fps, drag a window around & it will lift to 10 or more, a video will try to run at the broadcast frame rate, a game as fast as it can [unless limited].

Comment: Well, actually there is no problem whatsoever. I just curious how to read this report. In particular what are Sample Range, WS Wait length, WS Work length etc.